# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel (while debugging same code is working fine)

Tags: c#, ssl, httpclient, tls1.2

```
 public async Task<string>  FetchUser(FetchUser postdata)
 {

     try
     {
         ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
         ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
         System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
       

         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        

         var Message = "";
        

         string apiUrl = ApiSecrets.ApiEndPoint;
         var payload = new
         {
             api_key = ApiSecrets.ApiKey,
             datasetKey = ApiSecrets.DataSetKey
            
         };
         string payloadJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
         var content = new StringContent(payloadJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

         string username = ApiSecrets.AuthUserName;
         string password = ApiSecrets.AuthPassword;
         string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
         // HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {

             // Read and print the response content
             string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             // string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
             JsonResponse Empresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(responseBody);
             List<Employee> employees = Empresponse.employee_data;
             

         }
         else
         {
             // Handle unsuccessful response
             //  Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.StatusCode);
             Message = "Invalid Response";
         }

         return Message;

     }
     //Genearl ex
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         if (ex.InnerException != null)
         {
             // Log or inspect the InnerException details
             // Console.WriteLine($"InnerException: {ex.InnerException.Message}");

             // Throw the InnerException to propagate it
             throw ex.InnerException;
         }

         // If there is no InnerException, rethrow the original exception
         throw ex;
     }
     //General Ex end

 }
```

I'm encountering an issue with my C# code that makes HTTP requests using HttpClient to an api endpoint.  The error message is "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." Strangely, the same code works fine when I debug it on my local system.

```
{
    "status_code": 500,
    "request_name": "FetchUser",
    "message": "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.",
    "request_time": ,
    "response_time":,
    "response_time_Utc": 0,
    "data": "Failure"
}
```

Comment: maybe due lack of certificate ?

Comment: _"works fine when I debug it on my local system"_ what system is it running on. Specifically, what operating system? This will have a large say in how TLS is handled.

Comment: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` just why? Why are youm essing with protocols in the application? You need to instead check your system has the latest updates, and has TLS1.2 enabled in the registry. Also `throw ex;` is going to wipe the stack trace, don't ever do that, should be `throw;` instead. You are also missing a bunch of `using` blocks.

Comment: Probably the System where this fails cannot provide required cipher suites. As already mentioned, you have to specify in what System version this succeeds and in what other version it fails -- See [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-) and [Cipher Suites in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel) -- If needed, get [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) (free software) for the comparison

Comment: .net framework version
<compilation targetFramework="4.7.2" debug="true" />
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />

My local os version
Microsoft windows 11 pro

Server Os version
windows server 2012 r2 edition

I have instlled iis crypto
only difference i can see that is in my local in server and client protocol tls 1.3 is there but in server its not there

i tried by disabling tls 1.3 in local but in that case also it worked in my local

Comment: You didn't check the Cipher Suites, there is the difference. Windows Server 2012 R2 is out of support, and it doesn't have the more recent cipher suites that many end points require, at this time. There's nothing you can do either, unless you do what the major web browser do: these have their own cipher suites (and handle them)

Comment: I have Reached out to my api endpoint provider,its like they only support tls1.3 for calling of the apis ,is there any way we can call their apis hosted in server which has tls 1.3 from our current server